# Javascript - Remove a particular type(string,int) of element from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

With `array1` :

```
array1 = [["hello",1],["bye",2]]
```

By the way `array1[0]` return `["hello",1]` and not `["hello"]`

How can I get (in a new, or the same array) :

```
array2 = [[1],[2]]
```

Note my `array1` have (in reality) a lot of elements.

Thanks.

Comment: And where did you get stuck, what have you tried?

Comment: array1[0][0] is the hello

Comment: Loop trough the arrays, check if typeof[x][y] ==="String", if yes, then remove it

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers ... Still don't understand why I go a "-2" to my post ... Maybe because i'm french, maybe because my english was bad .. I don't care anyway. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use [**`Array#map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var array1 = [
  ["hello", 1],
  ["bye", 2]
];
var array2 = array1.map(function(item) {
  return [item[1]];
});
console.log(array2);
```

**Or to retrieve only `Numbers`**

```js
var array1 = [
  ["hello", 1],
  ["bye", 2]
];
var array2 = array1.map(function(item) {
  return item.filter(function(val){ return isNaN(val); });
});
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rayon =) Really fast answer, working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map` and `filter` functions

```js
var array1 = [ ["hello", 1], ["bye", 2] ]

var array2 = array1.map(a => a.filter(b => typeof b != 'string'))

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

If you have ES5 then

```
array1.map(function(x) { return x[1] })
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most elegant solution but I tested it in jsconsole and it works. You can also test it in Dev Tools

```js
var array1 = [["hello",1],["bye",2]]
var numbers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) { 
    numbers.push(array1[i].filter((a) => +(a))) 
}

console.log(numbers);
```

Note: This requires typescript

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectElements(array, type) {
    var result = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         var arr = [];
         for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
              if (typeof array[i][j] === type) {
                  arr.push(array[i][j]);
              }
         }
         result.push(arr)
    }
   return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
var array2 = selectElements(yourArray, "string")
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array. Check if the item is a number. if so, push it to a new array, and splice it out of the old

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (typeof array1[i] === 'number') {
        newArray.push(array1[i]);
        array1.splice(i, 1);
    {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop the array and remove the string. Splice works with the position (0 in your case) and the number elements ( 1 element to remove )

`for (var i=0; i < array1.length; i++){
  array1[i].splice(0,1);
}`

Result: [[1][2]]